# Decentralised hosting websites linked to smart contracts

Tags: block-producer, web, ipfs, decentralization

Are there any plans for block producers to be able to serve HTTP from IPFS, etc, to allow for decentralisation? Has there been any discussion around this?

I've been trying to determine how this would be possible. Each BP could server a high performance HTTP server, with load balancing, etc. This might also mean DNS would have to be handled by block producers too, maybe in a round robin fashion so it's distributed evenly.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need static hosting and you don't need a custom domain, then you can use GitHub Pages, which is free. This will serve your site over https, which you need if you're using recent browser features, e.g. the built-in cryptographic functions.

Comment: Sorry, I was aiming at a decentralised solution. I'll update my question.